# How do I XML Serialize a object without a parameter-less constructor?

Tags: .net, vb.net, serialization, xmlserializer

I am trying to use the Application Settings feature of Visual Studios to easy save the setting of my program. One of the class I am trying to serialize contains a number of DenseMatrix objects from the MathNet.Numerics library. The DenseMatrix class does not have a parameter-less constructor so when calling My.Settings.Save() the serialization would crash. I tried replacing the matrices with a Double(,) but that crashed as well. I then tried writing some code to wrap a DenseMatrix as follows but it also failed I am guessing because all the bases classes have to have parameter-less constructors but I am not sure. Is there another logical way to store the matrices that can be automatically serialized by My.Settings.Save?

```
 <SettingsSerializeAs(SettingsSerializeAs.Xml)>
 Public Class AvtMatrix
    Inherits DenseMatrix
    Public Sub New()
       My.Base.New(3,3)
    End Sub
  End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digging into some of the IL, it looks like this uses `XmlSerializer` - in which case, the only answer is: you can't - it demands a public parameterless constructor. You *can cheat a little*, though - with `[Obsolete]`; this works, for example:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    public Foo(string bar)
    {
        Bar = bar;
    }
    [Obsolete("You don't look like a serializer", true)]
    public Foo()
    {
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo));
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            ser.Serialize(ms, new Foo("abc"));
            ms.Position = 0;
            Foo clone = (Foo)ser.Deserialize(ms);
            Console.WriteLine(clone.Bar); // "abc"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are just using Obsolete to tell the end user not to call the parameter-less constructor right? Here is no way to use this trick to wrap the DenseVector class right because I don't have access to that code and just inheriting and adding a parameter-less constructor does not seem to work.

Comment: @AlexanderVanAtta indeed, the `[Obsolete]` prevents people using that constructor via the C# compiler. If you don't have access to the type, then frankly it is a bad choice to try serializing it like this. I would suggest using a simple DTO for serialization.